# What to put in the [project.scripts] table if scripts are not stored in the "src" directory?

Tags: python, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I have this package which follows the *[src layout](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/)*:

```
.
+-- scripts
|   \-- lorem.py
|
+-- src
|   \-- bar
|       |-- __init__.py
|       \-- bazqux.py
|
|-- .editorconfig
|-- .gitignore
|-- LICENSE
|-- pyproject.toml
\-- README.md
```

*pyproject.toml* has the following table:

```ini
[project.scripts]
foo = "bar.lorem:ipsum"
```

This is supposed to expose a command line executable called `foo` which will run the function `ipsum` in the file `./src/bar/lorem.py`, if I understand it correctly.

However, I want my scripts to stay in `scripts`, a sibling of `src`. `foo = "scripts.lorem:ipsum"` doesn't work: it leads to a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts'`, which is quite understandable.

What should I put in that field then? Or should I change the project layout instead?

Comment: `bar.lorem` is the **package name after installation**. It does not matter how the files are organized in the source directory. "However, I want my scripts to stay in scripts, a sibling of src" - this is nonsense; you are not taking into account the fact that **the process of installation entails copying files and folders** into the `site-packages` - in a way that does not necessarily reflect the organization of your project. `site-packages` **would not** contain a `src` folder, unless you actually want to define a package called `src.bar.lorem` and write the rest of pyproject.toml that way.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think you are misunderstanding a bit. I want to separate the scripts from the real package code, and I want the build backend to know that so that it can install them both correctly. In other words, if it "*does not matter how the files are organized in the source directory*", shouldn't I be able to make the build backend install my scripts no matter where they reside?

Comment: I think the details of that will depend on which build backend you are using. IIRC the PEPs don't really say enough about the contents of pyproject.toml, or mandate enough about the build process, to give a general solution. The answers you have so far seem like workarounds to me, although they may well be sufficient for your specific purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### setuptools

You didn't mention which [build backend](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/) you are using, but assuming it is `setuptools`, you are currently out of luck<sup>1</sup>.

`setuptools` [only supports generated scripts that use Python entry-points](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html#entry-points). These generated scripts work by importing a module at runtime and running a  specific function from it. You cannot reference code that is not importable at runtime.

There is currently no way to specify file scripts in the `scripts` table<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup> According to wim in the comments, *"[file scripts] may be specified as data files. It's deprecated but it still works, and there will hopefully be some [replacement](https://discuss.python.org/t/should-there-be-a-new-standard-for-installing-arbitrary-data-files/7853/1) ready before this feature is ever actually removed"*.</sup>

#### poetry

If you use [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) as your build backend, **using file scripts is possible**.

Currently, poetry only *officially* supports Python entry-points for packaged scripts (just like setuptools). However, poetry has *unofficial* support for file scripts (see [poetry-core#40](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry-core/pull/40) and [poetry#2310](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2310)).

File scripts can be specified by adding `type = "file"` to a script's table in `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.poetry.scripts]
foo = { reference = "scripts/lorem.py", type = "file" }
```

You should see the referenced files copied into `{name}-{version}.data/scripts` in your distribution's wheel files.

**One word of warning:** while file scripts are properly handled when installing your distribution with pip, they currently [are not processed when using `poetry install`](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2310#issuecomment-1563638061). If you want your file scripts to be copied into your virtual environment's bin directory, you will need to use `pip install .` instead of `poetry install`.

Comment: This part about setuptools is not true: _there is currently no way to specify file scripts_. They may be specified as data files. It's deprecated but it still works, and there will hopefully be some [replacement](https://discuss.python.org/t/should-there-be-a-new-standard-for-installing-arbitrary-data-files/7853/1) ready before this feature is ever actually removed (since there are several legitimate use-cases for non-Python scripts).

Comment: @wim If you can provide an example, I am sure that would be a welcome answer. In the meantime I've updated the wording of the sentence.

Comment: Indeed I'm using `setuptools`; had no idea different build backends interpret [the specs](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/) differently (even though I did read that page and find nothing about the possibility of having scripts stored in a non-standard directory).

Comment: If possible, could you also add information for other build backends like [Hatchling](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/), [flit](https://flit.pypa.io/en/latest/) and [PDM](https://pdm.fming.dev/latest/) too, so that others like me have more options to choose from?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to create a "private" (`_`-prefixed) package to store the scripts:

```
.
+-- src
|   |-- _bar_scripts (or whatever)
|   |   \-- lorem.py
|   |
|   \-- bar
|       |-- __init__.py
|       \-- bazqux.py
|
|-- .editorconfig
|-- .gitignore
|-- LICENSE
|-- pyproject.toml
\-- README.md
```

Alternatively, a private module directory (e.g. `./src/bar/_scripts/`) can also be used. <sub>(Thanks to @Brian61354270 for the suggestion.)</sub>

This will works correctly just as with a normal package:

```ini
[project.scripts]
foo = "_bar_scripts.lorem:ipsum"
```

...but it might not do if the script is meant to be imported by the end-user, since the `import` statement will look hideous (this is not the case for me, however):

```py
from _bar_scripts.lorem import ipsum
```

Comment: You could also put it inside a "private" submodule of `bar`, e.g. `bar._scripts`

Comment: That would also work, yes.

Answer (score 0):

### Hijacking console scripts to emulate file scripts

File scripts are not well standardized, so most popular build backends only provide support for console scripts with Python entry-points.

This answer details how to create a console script that will provide the functionality of an arbitrary file script.

#### Background: Generated console scripts

Given a console script configuration like

```ini
script_name = "foo.bar:main"
```

a typical build backend will generate a Python script that looks something like this:

```py
#!...
import sys
from foo.bar import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

This script will be installed to your virtual environment's bin directory as a file named `script_name`. (The full process is a bit more complicated, and the exact form of the generated script does vary between build backends)

#### Approach 1: Delegate to a package resource

This approach involves creating a console script that runs your desired file script in a subprocess.

Place your file script (let's call it `file_script`) inside your import package as a [package resource](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html). Make sure you build system is configured to include package resources with your package.

Then, somewhere in your package, create an entry-point like

```
import importlib.resources
import pathlib
import subprocess
import sys


def main():
    package_resources = importlib.resources.files(__name__)
    script_path = package_resources / "file_script"
    subprocess.run([script_path, *sys.argv[1:]])
```

This entry-point will run your file script inside a subprocess that inherits the parent process' stdin, stdout, and stderr. The functionality should be almost indistinguishable from running the file script directly, aside from the overhead of starting an additional process.

#### Approach 2: Self-installing file script

This approach is a bit more hacky, but allows you to save the overhead of starting an extra subprocess every time your script is run.

Our goal is to create a console script that will 1) locate the installed Python script that the build system generated, and 2)  *overwrite* the installed script with our desired file script.

This can be done with the following entry-point:

```py
import subprocess
import sys
import pathlib

# Example file script. Optionally, you can read this from a file.
SCRIPT = """\
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo 'It works!'
"""


def main():
    script_path = sys.modules["__main__"].__file__
    pathlib.Path(script_path).write_text(SCRIPT)
    subprocess.run([script_path, *sys.argv[1:]])
```

Here, we use `sys.modules["__main__"].__file__` to find the path to the installed console script. We then overwrite it with contents of our desired file script, so that all future runs of the script will execute the file script directly. Lastly, just for this first run, we execute the file script in a subprocess as we did in Approach 1.

After running your script for the first time, you should see that the script file in your virtual environment's bin directory has the contents

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo 'It works!'
```